# Laravel OrderByRaw column not found

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I Got a problem with `orderByRaw` Laravel.

Array:

```
$arr = [H123456, H7654321];
```

query:

```
$ids = implode(',', $arr);
$query = User::whereIn('id', $arr)->isActive()->orderByRaw(DB::raw("FIELD(id,". $ids.")"))->get();
```

This is the raw query:

```
"select * from `merchant_heads` where `id` in (?, ?) and `category_id` = ? and `status` = ? order by FIELD(id,Hf561b6fd32aec6ea,H7c81e6fa3f85fc74) limit 10 offset 0"
```

I've already put this inside my User model:

```
public $incrementing = false;
```

When i execute the query it says `Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'Hf561b6fd32aec6ea' in 'order clause'`.

I've tried to change $ids with single value like `1` it working. but it's not working if the ID is string like mine.

Any solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the ids are strings, you need to encapsulate them. Luckily, laravel can do it for you. Try with this:

```
$ids = implode(',', $arr);
$qs = array_fill(0,count($arr),'?');
$query = User::whereIn('id', $arr)->isActive()->orderByRaw(DB::raw("FIELD(id,". implode(',', $qs).")"),$arr)->get();
```

Comment: It's working perfectly. If you don't mind can you explain a little bit about `array_fill` ?

Comment: It creates an array with the length and values you specify. So in this case, it's creating an array with the exact number of question marks/placeholders as you have ids. Information on the function is at http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-fill.php .